# How does npm install command cause a change to the package permissions?

Tags: npm, angular-cli, centos7

I'm am on two different boxes, both of which are running the same version of npm and are on CENTOS7.

On one box the package permissions are left alone, date is left alone.

On the other box the package permissions are altered and the date of the file is marked as today.

Example.
after running the command

```
npm install --no-optional --save-exact
```

This file e.g.: **node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng**
has the permissions on one box as

> rwxr-x--- date is marked as today

the other box as

> rw-r----- has original date

The source on the npm repo has ***rw-r-----***.

What / where should I be looking to see how and why the permissions are being altered?
The correct permission for us would be for it to be an executable in order for us to run the ng build.

Is there some global setting for npm that maybe the box that appears to alter it is pulling some local modified copy from?

I have deleted the entire node_modules directory and its sub folders including the .bin/.

Hours lost here today trying to chase this down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not an NPM issue.
This was an issue with the Virus Scanner on the system.
After shutting off nails, npm install ran correctly and the file permissions were correct.